# Sqlalchemy class method error in models

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have declared some class Post with a method function to check itself, but apparently sqlalchemy is not recognizing it:

```
t.checkprofanity()
AttributeError: 'post' object has no attribute 'checkprofanity'
```

I am importing the class through:

```
Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

try:
    Post = Base.classes.post
```

and here is the class

```
class Post(db.Model):
    ...

    @classmethod
    def checkprofanity(self):
        ...   

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Post %r>' % (self.id)
```

Comment: your `__repr__` does work?

Comment: print(t) outputs <sqlalchemy.ext.automap.post object at 0x10f14f470>

Comment: t gives no output

Comment: Basically, I have a frontend (in flask) where i declared the models. From the frontend, everything works fine. I try to get the classes from the backend with Base.classes... Apparently, it does not get the methods inside the class.

Comment: `from ..path_to_file.. import Post`?

Comment: Front & backend are in different servers, so i preferred to do it the other way. They both connect to the ddbb

Comment: Confirmed, in the frontend it works fine.. I also tried to use an hybrid_class but it is not working.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is not possible to load class methods using reflection in sqlalchemy. They are just for dumping the ddbb structure as the get the reflected structure from the ddbb (so it does not contain that info).